# Getting coordinates and names for a driving route

Tags: google-maps

Is there any way to get the geo coordinates for a driving direction from Google Maps API?

if we use URL to show the driving direction with source and destination address we'll get the map and route as an webpage, instead of that I like to get the co-ordinates and details in some XML like format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hai all, 
Finally i got the solution, google also provides the driving directions in JSON format, we can parse the JSON data and that will give all the details including coordinates, name, description, distance and approximate time

example:

http://maps.google.com/maps/nav?key=YOUR-MAP-KEY&output=json&q=from:sourceAddress to: destinationAddress

Thank you all for the support

Answer (score 3):

Sure, see [the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html). You make a [GDirections](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Directions) object (without a `div` AND without a `map` so nothing will be displayed by default and you'll handle all the displaying), and call its `load` method, specifying `getPolyline` and `getSteps` as both true (so you'll get the polyline and the textual directions despite the lack of div and map).

The GDirections' object `load` event fires when the results are ready.  Then you use `getPolyline`, `getNumRoutes`, and `getRoute` methods on the object to retrieve results.

As a full reference, also check [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GDirections) (both GDirections and GDirectionsOptions)...!

Answer (score 0):

The [Google API documentation has a section on XML requests and parsing](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#XML_Requests).  It's quite detailed, many options available.